# res.sendFile send static file + object

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I have to serve a html file with express, but also want to send an object along with the response.
How can i send both - the detail.html and the object 'car' - and how can i access it at the client side?

```
app.get('/unit/:id', function (req, res) {
console.log(req.params.id)
var car = {type:"Fiat", model:"500", color:"white"};
res.sendFile(__dirname + '/detail.html', car);
});
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33027089/res-sendfile-in-node-express-with-passing-data-along

Answer (score 3):

Not really sure about your current setup but you might want to restructure your express app a little. You need to define a view engine and use

```
res.render('someview', dataObject);
```

http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render

with ejs:

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

route:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {  
  res.render('index', { title: 'The index page!' })
});
```

html:

```
<div>  
    <%= title %>
</div>
```

Comment: in this case i would like to avoid using the template-engine and render the plain html.

Comment: if that's the case, you can't do anything with the Object in the view. That's what template engines are for. look at this for example: https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars . They basically build the template before it's sent to the client. You would have to come up with some hybrid workaround otherwise.

Comment: okay, let´s assume i am using ejs engine to render the HTML. how do i receive the object at the frontend? how does my javascript have to look like. i have no clue...

Comment: edited my answer. Took the example from here: http://robdodson.me/how-to-use-ejs-in-express/

Answer (score 2):

`res.sendFile` has to set some special headers (`Content-Disposition` paired with a `Content-Type`) so the browser will understand that an attachment its comming and based on the file type and browser either show the save dialog or open the file

What you could do is send the car object as a json with `res.json` and in the frontend check that the json was fetched so you can hit a second endpoint which will trigger the download